# load a template in angularjs form

Tags: java, angularjs, forms, post

I am using AngularJs in MVC with Java. I'm trying to change a classic form with an action to an angular form, but I can't load a new jsp after submit button is called. How can I do it?

On the success event I get the jsp as plaintext, but I don't know what I have to do with it. Thank you so much!

### index.jsp

```jsp
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="myController" ng-submit="login()"> 
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="user.name" />
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password"  />
        <input type="submit" value="Acceder" />     
    </form>         
</body>
```

### index.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/myApplication/Login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data:  $scope.user
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data); // --> "<html> <head><title>client</title></head>.... </html>"
        });
    };
});
```

### LoginControllerServlet.java

```java
public class LoginControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //... 
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("./client.jsp");
        //...
        rd.forward(request, response);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The post request should return an json object rather than redirecting to another jsp, the routing has to be done in the front end. Read about angular routers.